# How to segue to a gameScene from a storyboard Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a game project with gameScene and another Xcode project with a view controller. I want to be able to segue to the gameScene from the viewController.

Any ideas on how to do that? I'm using swift 2 on Xcode 7

So far, I have put the two projects in a Workspace but I do not know how to link the two.

Comment: Consider integrating gamescene inside project

Comment: Are both scenes available in interface builder?

Comment: @JuliusNaeumann they are in different projects, in different interface builders. I edited the question, it now says the two projects are in a workspace.

Comment: Can you import the gameScene class from the view controller class?